# Android удержание экрана в onTouch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, touch-event

Как узнать, сколько пользователь удерживает экран в `onTouch`?

---

У меня есть `onTouch` слушатель. Когда пользователь нажимает на экран, я изменяю `background'ы` некоторых `View`, когда пользователь отпускает экран — возвращаю. Мне нужно сделать так, если пользователь нажал на экран и не отпускает его 3 секунды, вызвать контекстное меню. Я знаю, как вызвать контекстное меню. Изначально я хотел создать поток, который попросту отсчитает эти 3 секунды, но потом подумал, может есть более простой способ?

Comment: Ну а `OnLongClickListener` использовать не вариант совсем?

Comment: @pavlofff, нет. Тут он совсем не уместен. Максимум, чтоб прервать поток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи надо создать наследника `CountDownTimer` и реализовать необходимые методы.

```
private class HoldTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public HoldTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

В обработчике нажатий реагировать соответствующим образом на определенные события:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        timer = new HoldTimer(holdTime, INTERVAL_UPDATE_PROGRESS);
        timer.start();
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        timer.cancel();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Я немного не понял, а что задается в параметрах? Первое секунды, которые нужно отсчитывать, а второе? И что сделать, если поток прервали (отпустили палец), какой метод включится?

Comment: @bukashka101 вторым параметром задается интервал с которым будет вызываться метод ```onTick```. Когда палец будет отпущен у объекта таймера вызовется метод ```cancel()```. Если таймер уже сработал, то ничего не произойдет, если еще не сработал, то метод ```onFinish()``` не будет вызван.

Comment: Вы точно правильно написали в последнем предложении "метод НЕ будет вызван"? И что делает метод `onTick`?

Comment: @bukashka101 Метод ```onTick``` просто вызывается, а делает он то, что вы в нем напишите. Да, точно, можете сами посмотреть в исходниках

Comment: Стоп, стоп, стоп. Я совсем запутался... Давайте по порядку: 1. Что вызывается при старте таймера. 2. Что вызывается при достижении 3х секунд. 3. Что вызывается при вызове `timer.cancel`?

Comment: @bukashka101 при старте ничего не вызывается, однако после старта с переодичностью ```countDownInterval``` начинает вызываться метод ```onTick```. Что в нем делать решаете вы, если ничего не надо, то просто оставьте его пустым. Методом ```cancel``` всего лишь устанавливается соответствующий флаг в класса ```CountDownTimer ```, который указывается на то, вызывать ли метод ```onFinish``` в конце отсчета или нет. Если вы установили таймер на 3 секунды, и а середине вызвали ```cancel```, то метод ```onFinish``` не будет вызван.

Comment: А при вызове `timer.start()` вызывается новый таймер или возобновляется старый?

Comment: @bukashka101 таймер перезапустится

Answer (score 0):

```
long eventDuration = event.getEventTime() - event.getDownTime();
```

**UPDATE:**
[Activity.registerForContextMenu(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) - вызвать контекстное меню при длинном нажатии на View

Comment: Так мне нужно время узнать до того, как пользователь палец отпустит!

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на тачскрин будет вызван `onDown`
если в это время запустить таймер который будет проверять не запущен ли `onUp`,
то значит пользователь все еще держит палец на тачсрине,
или как вариант почитать про `onPressed`...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("asd","TEXT");
            }
        },3000);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Окей вот тебе 2 строчки :)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {@Override public void run() { Log.e("asd", "TEXT"); } },3000); } return super.onTouchEvent(event); }
```

Comment: Вопрос был про то, есть ли более простой способ

Comment: Куда еще проще - то, 2 строчки кода). Этот 3 сек. таймер по памяти вообще ничто не весит. Главное отключить не забудьте.

Comment: Тогда что за таймер и как проверять?

Comment: Дак вы же написали выше что знаете как сделать). Создаешь обычный Таймер `Timer.schedule`. в методе `onTouch`, а в нем есть метод  `onDown` в нем и создавай таймер.

Comment: Я имел ввиду не таймер, а поток (я с таймером не сталкивался...). А не проще, если пользователь отпустил палец, останавливать таймер? И как, по достижению 3х секунд, выполнить какое-либо действие?

Comment: @bukashka101, Чисто логически это уже другое действие будет.

onDown нажал держит 3 сек, появляется сообщение. (аналог onPressed)
onDown нажал отпустил спустя 3 сек. появиться сообщение.

Comment: @bukashka101, выложил код.

Comment: @xTIGRx разве тут две строчки?

Comment: @Oceinic, Так и знал что напишешь)), выше написал спец для тебя :)

Comment: Стоп. А если пользователь уберет палец? Нужно же поток прервать! Как?

Comment: @bukashka101, Это уже другой вопрос, создайте новый вопрос и дайте мне ссылку я отвечу.

Comment: @xTIGRx, это должно входить в часть ответа. Без этой детали ответ не полный, а значит принять я его не могу.

Comment: @bukashka101, какой - то вы странный человек, жалобу на вас нужно кинуть думаю. 
Вопрос был такой "Как узнать, сколько пользователь удерживает экран в onTouch?"
Я пример кода показал, тоесть ответил на данный вопрос, а то что через час вы поняли что вам нужно еще что - то то это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @xTIGRx, смотрите глубже, вопрос в том, как сделать нужное мне.